# UICollectionView Self Sizing Cells with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to get self sizing `UICollectionViewCells` working with Auto Layout, but I can't seem to get the cells to size themselves to the content. I'm having trouble understanding how the cell's size is updated from the contents of what's inside the cell's contentView.

Here's the setup I've tried:

- Custom `UICollectionViewCell` with a `UITextView` in its contentView.
- Scrolling for the `UITextView` is disabled.
- The contentView's horizontal constraint is: "H:|[_textView(320)]", i.e. the `UITextView` is pinned to the left of the cell with an explicit width of 320.
- The contentView's vertical constraint is: "V:|-0-[_textView]", i.e. the `UITextView` pinned to the top of the cell.
- The `UITextView` has a height constraint set to a constant which the `UITextView` reports will fit the text.

Here's what it looks like with the cell background set to red, and the `UITextView` background set to Blue:
[image: cell background red, UITextView background blue]

I put the project that I've been playing with on GitHub [here](https://github.com/rawbee/SelfSizingCollectionViewCells).

Comment: Are you implementing the sizeForItemAtIndexPath method?

Comment: @DanielGalasko I'm not. My understanding is that the new self sizing cells feature in iOS 8 doesn't require you to do that any more.

Comment: not sure where you got that info from but you still need to, take a look at the WWDC excerpt http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/226

Comment: but again it depends on your use case, make sure you implement estimatedItemSize

Comment: @DanielGalasko That same video is what made me think that. "If you want to use self-sizing cells in UICollectionViewFlowLayout, it's one line.
...I replaced ItemSize with estimatedItemSize and that's it."

Comment: But since you are using a text view and you are updating the text on the fly you are going to have to implement the sizeThatFits method in your cell no?

Comment: **2019 - It's essential to go look at this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58108897/294884**

Answer (score 354, accepted):

> This answer is outdated from iOS 14 with the addition of compositional layouts. Please consider updating the [new API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views)

## Updated for Swift 5

`preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes` renamed to `preferredLayoutAttributesFitting` and use auto sizing

---

## Updated for Swift 4

`systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` renamed to `systemLayoutSizeFitting`

---

## Updated for iOS 9

After seeing my GitHub solution break under iOS 9 I finally got the time to investigate the issue fully. I have now updated the repo to include several examples of different configurations for self sizing cells. My conclusion is that self sizing cells are great in theory but messy in practice. A word of caution when proceeding with self sizing cells.

**TL;DR**

Check out my [GitHub project](https://github.com/danielgalasko/DGSelfSizingCollectionViewCells/tree/master)

---

Self sizing cells are only supported with flow layout so make sure thats what you are using.

There are two things you need to setup for self sizing cells to work.

#1. Set `estimatedItemSize` on `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

Flow layout will become dynamic in nature once you set the `estimatedItemSize` property.

```
self.flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
```

#2. Add support for sizing on your cell subclass

This comes in 2 flavours; Auto-Layout **or** custom override of `preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes`.

#### Create and configure cells with Auto Layout

I won't go to in to detail about this as there's a brilliant [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights) about configuring constraints for a cell. Just be wary that [Xcode 6 broke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25804588/auto-layout-in-uicollectionviewcell-not-working?rq=1) a bunch of stuff with iOS 7 so, if you support iOS 7, you will need to do stuff like ensure the autoresizingMask is set on the cell's contentView and that the contentView's bounds is set as the cell's bounds when the cell is loaded (i.e. `awakeFromNib`).

Things you do need to be aware of is that your cell needs to be more seriously constrained than a Table View Cell. For instance, if you want your width to be dynamic then your cell needs a height constraint. Likewise, if you want the height to be dynamic then you will need a width constraint to your cell.

#### Implement `preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes` in your custom cell

When this function is called your view has already been configured with content (i.e. `cellForItem` has been called). Assuming your constraints have been appropriately set you could have an implementation like this:

```
//forces the system to do one layout pass
var isHeightCalculated: Bool = false

override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
    //Exhibit A - We need to cache our calculation to prevent a crash.
    if !isHeightCalculated {
        setNeedsLayout()
        layoutIfNeeded()
        let size = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(layoutAttributes.size)
        var newFrame = layoutAttributes.frame
        newFrame.size.width = CGFloat(ceilf(Float(size.width)))
        layoutAttributes.frame = newFrame
        isHeightCalculated = true
    }
    return layoutAttributes
}
```

**NOTE** On iOS 9 the behaviour changed a bit that could cause crashes on your implementation if you are not careful (See more [here](https://github.com/danielgalasko/DGSelfSizingCollectionViewCells/issues/4)). When you implement `preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes` you need to ensure that you only change the frame of your layout attributes once. If you don't do this the layout will call your implementation indefinitely and eventually crash. One solution is to cache the calculated size in your cell and invalidate this anytime you reuse the cell or change its content as I have done with the `isHeightCalculated` property.

#### Experience your layout

At this point you should have 'functioning' dynamic cells in your collectionView. I haven't yet found the out-of-the box solution sufficient during my tests so feel free to comment if you have. It still feels like `UITableView` wins the battle for dynamic sizing IMHO.

##Caveats
Be very mindful that if you are using prototype cells to calculate the estimatedItemSize - this will break if your [XIB uses size classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735341/offscreen-uitableviewcells-for-size-calculations-not-respecting-size-class). The reason for this is that when you load your cell from a XIB its size class will be configured with `Undefined`. This will only be broken on iOS 8 and up since on iOS 7 the size class will be loaded based on the device (iPad = Regular-Any, iPhone = Compact-Any). You can either set the estimatedItemSize without loading the XIB, or you can load the cell from the XIB, add it to the collectionView (this will set the traitCollection), perform the layout, and then remove it from the superview. Alternatively you could also make your cell override the `traitCollection` getter and return the appropriate traits. It's up to you.

---

Comment: I have also tried for many hours to get dynamic sized cells in a flow layout to work and they work about 90% of the time. But some of the time cells are missing or in the wrong place, and if you scroll around the collection view sometimes the missing cells will appear or disappear. A lot of the time the missing cells are at the end of the view.

Changing the estimatedSize makes a huge difference in how things work and how fast the view reloads, contrary to the doc, which implies it's just an optimization.

My conclusion is that it's just too flakey to be useful beyond the most simple examples.

Comment: @DanielGalasko what if you have more than one xib for the cells? meaning three different layout cells? how would you implement the "calculateStandAlonecellHeight"? I tried everything in here except for the "calculateStandAloneCellHeight" the problem is if I "reloadData" in "Landscape" orientation and then switch back to portrait, somehow the new cells that appear after this rotation have a different size than what the "preferedLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes" return

Comment: 1: you need to make sure that your layout is invalidated when the bounds changes. Flow layout has an override for this. The same way you know what cell to dequeue in cellForRow is how you know what cell to use to calculate the height @ShabarinathPabba

Comment: I have a customcollectionview cell and this [self.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)].height is returning zero always. I am doing all the steps that has been suggested.

Comment: @Sana then your constraints are most likely wrong. Please see my link about configuring constraints on a cell:)

Comment: This appears to be fundamentally broken on iOS 9 GM. Setting `estimatedItemSize` leads to crashes -- there seems to be some huge bug in how auto layout is trying to process the UICollectionViewCell.

Comment: your solution as others say does not work always. Try changing the constraints of a cell after selection and deselection for ex. The whole collection breaks again. The Auto sizing is broken on ios9! I will revert back to use itemSize delegate and do the calculations myself.

Comment: @JoãoNunes completely agree. It's impossible to get it working so I also use normal delegate size calculation. I thought you managed to get estimatedItemSize working. I know if you change the layout as well it crashes

Comment: I find that simply implementing a "preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes" in my custom UICollectionViewCell that simply returns the layout parameter fixes sizing issues on reused cells. This effectively disables the default version of the function, if I include a call to the super version, again the sizing fails.

Comment: Hi, this works well if my collectionView is static, but if I add some cells (and it won't fit on the screen), the last cells are displayed only when I scroll. If I invalidate the flow's layout in the viewWillLayoutSubviews, it works well on ios10, but infinite loop on ios9, if I invalidate the layout after I reload the collectionView, it works well on ios10, but breaks on ios9 after adding a few cells, any idea?

Comment: As of Xcode 10 and iOS 12, this only works when loading the first cells. I fixed it by removing the `isHeightCalculated` test. Seems to work now and no memory leak as I can tell.

Comment: A BIG caveat here for me was that xibs use size classes. That breaks everything right off the bat. Had to implement my cell subclass entirelty in code

Comment: One thing I noticed that's missing in your code. You're setting width of the newFrame, but not height. Since we're using systemLayoutSizeFitting to get the size it includes the height. Since we are talking about dynamic heights mostly, I think the code should be updated for future reference when other people run into this.

Comment: Why are the calls to setNeedsLayout and layoutIfNeeded required? They solved my problem and I wanted an explanation because I couldnt come up with it. If I didnt use them then systemLayoutSizeFitting is returning erroneous sizes.

Comment: Why is it accepted as an answer? Using of `isHeightCalculated` with your example means you will get incorrect size on cell reusing

Answer (score 66):

In iOS10 there is new constant called `UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize` (formerly `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize`), so instead:

```
self.flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
```

you can use this:

```
self.flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
```

It has better performance especially when cells in your collection view have constant width.

**Accessing Flow Layout:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   if let flowLayout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
      flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
   }
}
```

**Swift 5 Updated:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   if let flowLayout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
      flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you set this? in viewdidload?  How do you get a handle on flowlayout?

Comment: I managed to implement this - but it has a strange behaviour that makes it center the cells if there is a single cell.  Here is the stack overflow question about it - has me stumped: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43266924/stop-single-uicollectionview-cell-flowing-to-the-centre-of-the-screen/43269736?noredirect=1

Comment: You can access the flow layout via the collectionViews `collectionViewLayout` and just check that it is of type `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

Comment: it makes my cells very small, useless

Answer (score 46):

A few key changes to [Daniel Galasko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25896386/4447090) fixed all my problems. Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to comment directly (yet).

In step 1, when using Auto Layout, simply add a single parent UIView to the cell. EVERYTHING inside the cell must be a subview of the parent. That answered all of my problems. While Xcode adds this for UITableViewCells automatically, it doesn't (but it should) for UICollectionViewCells. According to the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollingViewContent/ScrollingViewContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008179-CH6-SW2):

> To configure the appearance of your cell, add the views needed to present the data item’s content as subviews to the view in the contentView property. Do not directly add subviews to the cell itself.

Then skip step 3 entirely. It isn't needed.

Comment: Interesting; this is specifically for Xibs but nevertheless thanks, will try and muddle with the Github project and see if I can reproduce. Maybe divide the answer into Xib vs programmatic

Comment: always add subviews to the `contentView` property of UICollectionViewCell and UITableViewCell

Answer (score 37):

In iOS 10+ this is a very simple 2 step process.

1. Ensure that all your cell contents are placed within a single UIView (or inside a descendant of UIView like UIStackView which simplifies autolayout a lot). Just like with dynamically resizing UITableViewCells, the whole view hierarchy needs to have constraints configured, from the outermost container to the innermost view. That includes constraints between the UICollectionViewCell and the immediate childview
2. Instruct the flowlayout of your UICollectionView to size automatically

   ```
   yourFlowLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
   ```

Comment: Im curious, how would wrapping your cells contents in a UIView make Auto Layout perform better? Id have thought it would perform better with a more shallow hierarchy?

Comment: I did not mention performance, only simplicity. Self-sizing cells will only work if you have constraints spanning all the way between left and right, and between top and bottom. Achieving that is easiest when all views are wrapped in a single container. If that container is a UIStackView it is easier that if it is any other descendant of UIView.

Comment: Using Swift 4.1, Xcode tells me `UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize` has been renamed to `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize`.

Answer (score 14):

1. Add flowLayout on viewDidLoad()

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad() 
       if let flowLayout = infoCollection.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
           flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height:1)
       }
   }
   ```
2. Also, set an UIView as mainContainer for your cell and add all required views inside it.
3. Refer to this awesome, mind-blowing tutorial for further reference:
   [UICollectionView with autosizing cell using autolayout in iOS 9 & 10](https://medium.com/@wasinwiwongsak/uicollectionview-with-autosizing-cell-using-autolayout-in-ios-9-10-84ab5cdf35a2)

Answer (score 11):

EDIT 11/19/19: For iOS 13, just use UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout with estimated heights.  Don't waste your time dealing with this broken API.

After struggling with this for some time, I noticed that resizing does not work for UITextViews if you don't disable scrolling:

```
let textView = UITextView()
textView.scrollEnabled = false
```

Comment: when I try to scroll, the collection view cell is not smooth. Do you have any solution for this ?.

Comment: this doesn't work at all

Answer (score 9):

## contentView anchor mystery:

In one bizarre case this

```
    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

would not work. Added four explicit anchors to the contentView and it worked.

```
class AnnoyingCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet var word: UILabel!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame); common() }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder); common() }
    
    private func common() {
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor),
            contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor),
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
}
```

and as usual

```
    estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
```

in `YourLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

Who knows? Might help someone.

## Credit

https://www.vadimbulavin.com/collection-view-cells-self-sizing/

stumbled on to the tip there - never saw it anywhere else in all the 1000s articles on this.

Answer (score 4):

I did a dynamic cell height of collection view. Here is [git hub repo](https://github.com/imyoungyang/DynamicHeight).

And, dig out why preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes is called more than once. Actually, it will be called at least 3 times.

The console log picture :
[image]

**1st preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes**:

```
(lldb) po layoutAttributes
<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x7fa405c290e0> index path: (<NSIndexPath:    0xc000000000000016> 
{length = 2, path = 0 - 0}); frame = (15 12; 384 57.5); 

(lldb) po self.collectionView
<UICollectionView: 0x7fa40606c800; frame = (0 57.6667; 384 0);
```

The layoutAttributes.frame.size.height is current status **57.5**.

**2nd preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes**:

```
(lldb) po layoutAttributes
<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x7fa405c16370> index path: (<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> 
{length = 2, path = 0 - 0}); frame = (15 12; 384 534.5); 

(lldb) po self.collectionView
<UICollectionView: 0x7fa40606c800; frame = (0 57.6667; 384 0);
```

The cell frame height changed to **534.5** as our expected. But, the collection view still zero height.

**3rd preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes**:

```
(lldb) po layoutAttributes
<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x7fa403d516a0> index path: (<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> 
{length = 2, path = 0 - 0}); frame = (15 12; 384 534.5); 

(lldb) po self.collectionView
<UICollectionView: 0x7fa40606c800; frame = (0 57.6667; 384 477);
```

You can see the **collection view height was changed from 0 to 477**.

The behavior is similar to handle scroll:

```
1. Before self-sizing cell

2. Validated self-sizing cell again after other cells recalculated.

3. Did changed self-sizing cell
```

At beginning, I thought this method only call once. So I coded as the following:

```
CGRect frame = layoutAttributes.frame;
frame.size.height = frame.size.height + self.collectionView.contentSize.height;
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* newAttributes = [layoutAttributes copy];
newAttributes.frame = frame;
return newAttributes;
```

This line:

```
frame.size.height = frame.size.height + self.collectionView.contentSize.height;
```

will cause system call infinite loop and App crash.

Any size changed, it will validate all cells' preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes again and again until every cells' positions (i.e frames) are no more change.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to above answers,

Just make sure you set *estimatedItemSize* property of *UICollectionViewFlowLayout* to some size and **do not** implement *sizeForItem:atIndexPath* delegate method.

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

The solution comprises 3 simple steps:

1. Enabling dynamic cell sizing

`flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize`

2. Set the containerView.widthAnchor.constraint from `collectionView(:cellForItemAt:)`to limit the width of contentView to width of collectionView.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    ...

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! MultiLineCell
        cell.textView.text = dummyTextMessages[indexPath.row]
        cell.maxWidth = collectionView.frame.width
        return cell
    }

    ...
}
```

```
class MultiLineCell: UICollectionViewCell{
    ....

    var maxWidth: CGFloat? {
        didSet {
            guard let maxWidth = maxWidth else {
                return
            }
            containerViewWidthAnchor.constant = maxWidth
            containerViewWidthAnchor.isActive = true
        }
    }

    ....
}
```

Since you want to enable self-sizing of UITextView, it has an additional step to;

#### 3. Calculate and set the heightAnchor.constant of UITextView.

So, whenever the width of contentView is set we'll adjust height of UITextView along in `didSet` of `maxWidth`.

Inside UICollectionViewCell:

```
var maxWidth: CGFloat? {
    didSet {
        guard let maxWidth = maxWidth else {
            return
        }
        containerViewWidthAnchor.constant = maxWidth
        containerViewWidthAnchor.isActive = true
        
        let sizeToFitIn = CGSize(width: maxWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))
        let newSize = self.textView.sizeThatFits(sizeToFitIn)
        self.textViewHeightContraint.constant = newSize.height
    }
}
```

These steps will get you the desired result.

#### [Complete runnable gist](https://gist.github.com/jolasjoe/d2fd89cbd8e8e213ed3c280f08a08f0b)

Reference: [Vadim Bulavin](https://twitter.com/V8tr) blog post - [Collection View Cells Self-Sizing: Step by Step Tutorial](https://www.vadimbulavin.com/collection-view-cells-self-sizing/)

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @Alex what about horizontal Scrolling collection view with dynamic height?

Answer (score 1):

The example method above does not compile.  Here is a corrected version (but untested as to whether or not it works.)

```
override func preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes(layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes 
{
    let attr: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes = layoutAttributes.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes

    var newFrame = attr.frame
    self.frame = newFrame

    self.setNeedsLayout()
    self.layoutIfNeeded()

    let desiredHeight: CGFloat = self.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
    newFrame.size.height = desiredHeight
    attr.frame = newFrame
    return attr
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you implement UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout method:

`- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath`

When you call `collectionview performBatchUpdates:completion:`, the size height will use `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` instead of 
`preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes`.

The rendering process of `performBatchUpdates:completion` will go through the method `preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes` but it ignores your changes.

Comment: I've seen this misbehavior, but only when the estimated size is zero.  Are you sure you're setting an estimated size?

Answer (score 1):

To whomever it may help,

I had that nasty crash if `estimatedItemSize` was set. Even if I returned 0 in `numberOfItemsInSection`. Therefore, the cells themselves and their auto-layout were not the cause of the crash... The collectionView just crashed, even when empty, just because `estimatedItemSize` was set for self-sizing.

In my case I reorganized my project, from a controller containing a collectionView to a collectionViewController, and it worked.

Go figure.

Comment: Try calling `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()` after `collectionView.reloadData()`.

Comment: for ios10 and below add this code `    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {

        } else {
            mainCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        }
    }`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who tried everything without luck, this is the only thing that got it working for me. 
For the multiline labels inside cell, try adding this magic line:

```
label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 200
```

More info: [here](https://possiblemobile.com/2016/02/sizing-uicollectionviewcell-fit-multiline-uilabel)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Update more information:

- If you use `flowLayout.estimatedItemSize`, suggest use iOS8.3 later version. Before iOS8.3, it will crash `[super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];`.
  The error message is

  `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'`
- Second, in iOS8.x version, `flowLayout.estimatedItemSize` will cause different section inset setting did not work. i.e. function: `(UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:`.

Answer (score 0):

My collection view class has: ☝️

```
override var contentSize: CGSize {
           didSet {
               invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
           }
       }
```

My collection view: ☝️ (For cells auto-sizing)

```
let buttonsCollectionView: ContentCollectionView = {
        var cv = ContentCollectionView()
        if let collectionViewLayout = cv.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            collectionViewLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
        }
        return cv
    }()

buttonsCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
buttonsCollectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
```

Cell look like:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        title.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 16),
        title.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
        title.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
        title.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
    ])
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried using `estimatedItemSize` but there were a bunch of bugs when inserting and deleting cells if the `estimatedItemSize` was not exactly equal to the cell's height. i stopped setting `estimatedItemSize` and implemented dynamic cell's by using a prototype cell. here's how that's done:

create this protocol:

```
protocol SizeableCollectionViewCell {
    func fittedSize(forConstrainedSize size: CGSize)->CGSize
}
```

implement this protocol in your custom `UICollectionViewCell`:

```
class YourCustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, SizeableCollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet private var mTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private var mDescription: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private var mContentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet private var mTitleTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet private var mDesciptionBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    func fittedSize(forConstrainedSize size: CGSize)->CGSize {

        let fittedSize: CGSize!

        //if height is greatest value, then it's dynamic, so it must be calculated
        if size.height == CGFLoat.greatestFiniteMagnitude {

            var height: CGFloat = 0

            /*now here's where you want to add all the heights up of your views.
              apple provides a method called sizeThatFits(size:), but it's not 
              implemented by default; except for some concrete subclasses such 
              as UILabel, UIButton, etc. search to see if the classes you use implement 
              it. here's how it would be used:
            */
            height += mTitle.sizeThatFits(size).height
            height += mDescription.sizeThatFits(size).height
            height += mCustomView.sizeThatFits(size).height    //you'll have to implement this in your custom view

            //anything that takes up height in the cell has to be included, including top/bottom margin constraints
            height += mTitleTopConstraint.constant
            height += mDescriptionBottomConstraint.constant

            fittedSize = CGSize(width: size.width, height: height)
        }
        //else width is greatest value, if not, you did something wrong
        else {
            //do the same thing that's done for height but with width, remember to include leading/trailing margins in calculations
        }

        return fittedSize
    }
}
```

now make your controller conform to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`, and in it, have this field:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    private var mCustomCellPrototype = UINib(nibName: <name of the nib file for your custom collectionviewcell>, bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as! SizeableCollectionViewCell
}
```

it will be used as a prototype cell to bind data to and then determine how that data affected the dimension that you want to be dynamic

finally, the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout's` `collectionView(:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` has to be implemented:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    private var mDataSource: [CustomModel]

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)->CGSize {

        //bind the prototype cell with the data that corresponds to this index path
        mCustomCellPrototype.bind(model: mDataSource[indexPath.row])    //this is the same method you would use to reconfigure the cells that you dequeue in collectionView(:cellForItemAt:). i'm calling it bind

        //define the dimension you want constrained
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 20    //the width you want your cells to be
        let height = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude    //height has the greatest finite magnitude, so in this code, that means it will be dynamic
        let constrainedSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)

        //determine the size the cell will be given this data and return it
        return mCustomCellPrototype.fittedSize(forConstrainedSize: constrainedSize)
    }
}
```

and that's it. Returning the cell's size in `collectionView(:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` in this way preventing me from having to use `estimatedItemSize`, and inserting and deleting cells works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

In `Swift 5`, it works for me.

UICollectionViewFlowLayout:

```
estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
```

UICollectionViewCell:

(ps: I'm using SnapKit)

```
class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let customizedContentView = UIView()
    ...
    func layoutAction() {
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(customizedContentView)
        customizedContentView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

then you just need to expand `customizedContentView`.