# UICollectionView self-sizing-cell on iOS 8 will crash with UIDynamic flowLayout and repeating call to _updateVisibleCellsNow

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout, uikit-dynamics

I am trying to use the so called "self sizing cell" which means:

- set `estimatedItemSize` on `flowLayout`
- overide `preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes` in cell class

Such as this: [UICollectionView Self Sizing Cells with Auto Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895311/uicollectionview-self-sizing-cells-with-auto-layout)

And I need dynamic effect like this:http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/implementing-a-bouncy-uicollectionviewlayout-with-uikit-dynamics/

It works fine without UIDynamic, but I need UIDynamic. As what I see, it will call the `prepareLayout` and `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` until die, there will be too many `_updateVisibleCellsNow` waiting in line.

I have no idea how to solve that, please help me in case u see. Or, if I am using those technologies in wrong way, please let me know.

Answer (score 12):

Two things worked for me:

- Make sure your collection view itself has layout constraints defined for placement within its superview.
- I got this crash when the estimated size was larger than the final size.  If I set the estimated size to a smaller value the crash stopped.

Comment: This is true... Correct answer, I set estimatedItemSize = (0, 0)

Comment: For me, setting an `estimatedItemSize` of `.zero` disabled autosizing completely, but a size of (1.0, 1.0) fixed the infinite recursion of `_updateVisibleCellsNow:` on iOS 9

Answer (score 1):

If any size or frame position changed, it will trigger all cells' preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes until all cells' frames did not change.

The behavior flow is as the following:

```
1. Before self-sizing cell

2. Validated self-sizing cell again after other cells recalculated.

3. Did changed self-sizing cell
```

If second steps can't get stable all cells' position and size, it will become infinite loop.

Please reference my post here: [UICollectionView Self Sizing Cells with Auto Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895311/uicollectionview-self-sizing-cells-with-auto-layout/37070589#37070589)