# Why is the flow layout's section inset not respected when dynamic cell sizing is enabled in a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, flowlayout

According to many tutorials and posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25896386/2062785) on Stackoverflow a `UICollectionView`'s flow layout becomes dynamic once you set its `estimatedItemSize` property to a non-zero value. If this is the case the flow layout obtains each item size directly from the cells instead of asking the delegate method `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:`.

Unfortunately, setting the `estimatedItemSize` property also affects other flow layout delegate methods like `collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:`. I observed that once the `estimatedItemSize` is set this method is simply ignored, as well as the flow layout's `sectionInset` property.

With this method declaration:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 10, 20, 10);
}
```

my collection view looks like this with `estimatedItemSize` set:

[image: esimatedItemSize enabled]

and like this without `estimatedItemSize` set (and returning a fixed item size `CGSizeMake(300, 50)` from `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` instead):

[image: esimatedItemSize disabled]

Is there any reason for this kind of behavior? Why does the flow layout ignore the section insets for dynamic cell sizes?

Comment: Ran into the same thing.. seems like it's iOS 9 only :(

Comment: Is there an update on this?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not.