# How to display dynamically data from Server in CollectionViewCell in TableViewCell with swift3?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift3, uitableview

I got my json link data from TableViewCell , and then retrieve that data from server and display in collectionView with related TableViewCell data.
How to display this data in swift3? Please, help me.

I got url link (mainThemeList.main_associated_url,main_name) from TableViewCell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



        let mainThemeList = mainHomeThemeTable[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "homecell") as! HomeCategoryRowCell



         DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.categoryTitle.text = mainThemeList.main_name
            cell.mainAssociatedURL.text = mainThemeList.main_associated_url


            self.prefs.set(mainThemeList.main_name, forKey: "main_name")
            cell.categoryTitle.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17.0)
            cell.collectionView.reloadData()

        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            self.retrieveDataFromServer(associated_url: mainThemeList.main_associated_url,main_name: mainThemeList.main_name)
        }

        return cell
    }
```

And then data related url link data from Server.

```
 private func retrieveDataFromServe(associated_url : String , main_name: String) {
        SwiftLoading().showLoading()
        if Reachability().isInternetAvailable() == true {

            self.rest.auth(auth: prefs.value(forKey: "access_token") as! String!)
            rest.get(url: StringResource().mainURL + associated_url ,  parma: [ "show_min": "true" ], finished: {(result : NSDictionary, status : Int) -> Void in


                self.assetsTable.removeAll()
                if(status == 200){
                    let data = result["data"] as! NSArray
                    if (data.count>0){
                        for item in 0...(data.count) - 1 {

                            let themes : AnyObject = data[item] as AnyObject
                            let created = themes["created"] as! String
                            let assets_id = themes["id"] as! Int
                            let name = themes["name"] as! String
                            var poster_img_url = themes["poster_image_url"] as! String
                            let provider_id = themes["provider_id"] as! Int

                            poster_img_url = StringResource().posterURL + poster_img_url

                            self.assetsTable.append(AssetsTableItem(main_name: main_name,created: created,assets_id: assets_id, name: name, poster_image_url: poster_img_url,provider_id: provider_id))

                        }
                    }

                    SwiftLoading().hideLoading()

                }else{

                    SwiftLoading().hideLoading()

                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Retrieve data from Server data store in assetsTable.

And then assetsTable data display in CollectionViewCell.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {



    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "videoCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeVideoCell

            cell.movieTitle.text = list.name
            cell.imageView.image = list.image



    return cell

}
```

My problem is collectionViewCell data are duplicate with previous assetsTable data and didn't show correct data in CollectionView.

[image]

My tableViewCell show (Action, Drama) label and My CollectionViewCell show movies Name and Movie Image.  I retrieve data for CollectionViewCell from server but CollectionViewCell didn't display related data.

Comment: edit your question and make it more clear  to understand the scenario by adding some more stuffs.

Comment: So basically you are trying to use collection view with in the tableViewCell.
and your problem is related to the dequeue the table view cell.

You've to set separate the data for collection view of each tableViewCell, pass the data in tableView's cellForRowAtIndex that needed to be shown.

Each cell will contain/store/have it own collection view data.

Comment: Make and array of dictionary in tableViewCell's class and pass the respected data in cellForRowAtIndexPath of tableView retrieved from webservice.

Comment: my problem is that I may not know how many tableViewCell data from Server. It's tableViewCell data from server data are dynamic data. That's why separate CollectionView for Unknown amount data is not OK in my code.
@PramodKumar

Comment: You've to get the data from backend for each category like 
{
"Action" : [{"title":"The Dark Knight", "thumb":"url_of_thumb"},{"title": "The Godfather", "Thumb":"url_of_thumb"}]
"Drama": [{"title": "Malgudi Days", "Thumb":"url_of_thumb"}]
}
etc..

Then you have to create the total cell in table view according to the total keys of this dictionary ("Action", "Drama"). And then you've to send the action data to action cell's collectionView and drama data to drama cell's collectionView

Comment: i'm using third party service provider and I can't change api :( 
Thanks for your answer! @PramodKumar

Comment: No issue buddy, when you got the data from api parse it according to you as you want it to show.
break that data in to dictionaries that you want. (y)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147166/discussion-between-pramod-kumar-and-san-san).

Comment: You are calling `retrieveDataFromServer`, which is purging `assetsTable` and then populating that table. But you only have a single array of results at any given time. But that's not going to be adequate. You need a separate array for each row in your table (i.e. an array of arrays) and `retrieveDataFromServer` should update only its own entry in this master array of arrays model.

Comment: Unrelated, but your casual references to `cell` inside the `async` calls is very dangerous. You have no assurances that the cell hasn't been reused. When updating cells asynchronously, you have to call and re-retrieve the cell for that index path. This problem is unlikely to manifests itself here, but it is, nonetheless, dangerous.

Comment: BTW, in your `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:_)` is referencing `list`, but I don't see where that's populated. It feels like there's a missing detail here.

Comment: I highly recommend using StackOverflow as a place to explore your thinking and attempts at solving a problem. Just dumping your code and asking for help is not really fair on everyone else. Now I must spend time parsing through all your code with little effort made to illustrate how you have tried to debug this issue. Just some friendly advice that will help you get answers quickly in future

Comment: Below are a few things you need to check. Check the datasource/delegate. ViewController will be ur delegate/ds for ur tableview and ur tableview cell should act as the delegate/ds for your collectionview cell. The code that you posted seem to be disconnected, for eg the "list" that you use where you are populating it? Check this video it show a nice basic implementation of this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q1lGQhbtPC8

Answer (score 0):

in HomeVideoCell Subclass clean up data in **prepareforreuse**

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.movieTitle.text = ""
    self.imageView.image = nil
}
```

Comment: I can't call cell in HomeVideoCell.swift . How to call? @MeghsDhameliya