# Change UICollectionViewCell height to fit UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to make my cell height size fit with label. The thing is that the label text is set in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, and if i have understood correct, `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` runs before the `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. This is something i have tried so far:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let imageCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("imageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell

        imageCell!.imageText.text = post.text // This set the UICollectionView Cell text

        imageCell!.frame.size.height = (imageCell!.frame.size.height) + (imageCell!.imageText.frame.size.height)

        return imageCell!
    }
```

I am not using Auto Layout.

[image]

Any suggestions why the cell height not changes depending on the label?

Answer (score 1):

This used to be an annoying problem to solve, but it gets substantially easier if you're able to use Auto Layout. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895311/uicollectionview-self-sizing-cells-with-auto-layout) for a thorough walkthrough.

Comment: Problem i am not using Auto Layout: http://s8.postimg.org/zcok16nsl/Screen_Shot_2015_12_12_at_00_42_49.png

Answer (score -1):

Even if `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` runs first, that's the place to set the size of the cell. `cellForItemAtIndexPath` cannot change the size.

In `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` you need to find out the image size for each cell, then return that size.

Something like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let imageCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    let size = CGSize(width: imageCell.frame.width, height: imageCell.frame.size.height + imageCell.imageText.frame.size.height)
    return size

}
```

Comment: The question is how i should do it?

Comment: I updated, but really, it's the same code you had, just moved to the other function.

Comment: I get error: http://s27.postimg.org/vzvdugloj/Screen_Shot_2015_12_12_at_02_04_33.png - Did you ment to add the `imageCell!.frame.size.height = ` also?

Comment: And the error message you posted tells you the correct answer. You just had to convert to a CGSize. Updated

Comment: Bah, that also crashes: http://s27.postimg.org/8ckwubrc3/Screen_Shot_2015_12_12_at_18_56_54.png

Comment: Cast to your custom cell type. Updated.

Comment: Still getting that crash error: http://s1.postimg.org/fmsvm1pgf/Screen_Shot_2015_12_13_at_20_03_54.png