# UICollectionView auto layout with different cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am using `UICollectionView` with autolayout to display gallery. I have 2 types of `prototype cells`- one to display for 2-columned collectionView and one for 3-columned view.

On button click, the view is to be toggled to 2-columned and 3-columned

Following is my code:

```
    -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellGrid" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if([selected_layout isEqualToString:@"tile"]){
            cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellTile" forIndexPath:indexPath];  // for 2 columns
        } else {
            cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellGrid" forIndexPath:indexPath];  // for 3 columns
        }
[cell layoutIfNeeded];
    [cell setNeedsDisplay];

    return cell;
}
```

I am not setting cell's height/width anywhere in code, I have just specified it in xib. But everytime 3 columned `collectionView` is displayed with about 10 pixel black gap between each cell.

I referred [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895311/uicollectionview-self-sizing-cells-with-auto-layout) but it is using swift and custom cell classes. I don't want to use that.

How do I solve this? Where am I getting wrong?

Comment: if cell size varied means, you need to set cell size in collectio view, - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
referenceSizeForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if([selected_layout isEqualToString:@"tile"])
        return CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.size.width/3,50);
    else
        return CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.size.width/2,50);
}   like this

Comment: @NANNAV tried this, still the same. Why do I need to set footer size? `referenceSizeForFooterInSection `

Comment: have you checked the selected_layout value each time ?

Answer (score 1):

Add these delegate methods:

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionView *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{


        return 5;


}


- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 10, 10, 10);
}
```