# UICollectionView Different Item Height Issue

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

**Keypoints:**

1. I am using **XIB** with **Autolayout**

I am trying to create a `UICollectionView` that has a dynamic item height. This is needed because I have an `UILabel` that might have different heights due to it's length. The `UILabel`'s text is set using it's attributedText property

**I am aware that:**

1. I **MUST NOT** implement `sizeForItemAtIndexpath`.
2. I **MUST** set `estimatedItemSize` to the flowLayout of my `UICollectionView`.

I have been scavenging Stackoverflow for more than 6 hours but still unable to find solution but most of the solutions are either emphasizing on Storyboards or intended for lower version of iOS.

The best one i have found so far is this [UICollectionView Self Sizing Cells with Auto Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31279726/2224226)

However, that also did not fix my problem because somehow, my cell does not have the intended width.

Any ideas please?

.

.

*Please help me vote this up cause I am literally banging my head now. Any help is very welcome.*