# How do I set dynamic cell's height?

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

Hi I'm trying to set dynamic cell's height.

[image]

Here is my UICollectionViewCell

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ActiveLabel
class UserShopDetailCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var postImg: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var likesLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var commentLbl: ActiveLabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLbl: ActiveLabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var profileImg: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeLbl: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionTop: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var commentTop: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeTop: NSLayoutConstraint!


    override func awakeFromNib() {



    }


}
```

And It is collectionviewcontroller

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let cellsAcross: CGFloat = 3
    let spaceBetweenCells: CGFloat = 1
    let dim = (collectionView.bounds.width - (cellsAcross - 1) * spaceBetweenCells) / cellsAcross

    var width = 114.0


    if(isGridView==true){
        return CGSize(width: 114, height: 114)
    }
    else {



//I want set dynamic height...not constant values
        return CGSize(width: 375, height: 500)
    }


}




 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {



    if isGridView == false {

 let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "UserShopDetailCell", for: indexPath) as! UserShopDetailCell
```

...
.....
......

```
  let basicHeight = cell.frame.size.width + 23 + cell.usernameLbl.frame.height + 1 + cell.likesLbl.frame.height

            let bottomHeight = cell.timeTop.constant + cell.timeLbl.frame.height + 12

        var dynamicHeight = basicHeight + bottomHeight

         cell.frame.size.height = dynamicHeight
        cell.sizeToFit()
        cell.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: 375, height: dynamicHeight))
        cell.contentView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: 375, height: dynamicHeight))


return cell
}

}
```

[image]

As you can see.. white space is 500 height - dynamic height.

I want finally set cell's height from dynamic height values.

But When I set the CGSize then dynamic height is not working when is bigger than CGSize.

How Can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

follow these steps to create self sizing cells on collectionview. No need to use `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` method when creating cells using estimatedItemSize and auto layout.

1. set estimatedItemSize on collectionViewFlowlayout
2. use auto layout to set correct constraint for your collectionviewcell subclass

refer the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895311/uicollectionview-self-sizing-cells-with-auto-layout) and the [tutorial](http://corsarus.com/2015/collection-view-with-self-sizing-cells/) on how to use self sizing cells using auto layout

here is the [Github](https://github.com/danielgalasko/DGSelfSizingCollectionViewCells/tree/master) project link

Comment: Thanks for the reply could you let me know how do I use in swift.?