# Cell is in the center of collection view when there is only one cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, autolayout

I want to layout cells from left to right.So I use `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
// use this for let cell width fit for label width
layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(80, 30);
self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds collectionViewLayout:layout];
```

The cell's width is fit for the label's width:

```
// cell code
@implementation CQGoodsSearchCell

- (void)setupUI {
    self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
    self.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.00 green:1.00 blue:1.00 alpha:1.00];

    self.nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.nameLabel];
    self.nameLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    self.nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.18 green:0.18 blue:0.18 alpha:1.00];
    [self.nameLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.height.mas_equalTo(30);
        make.top.bottom.mas_offset(0);
        make.left.mas_offset(10);
        make.right.mas_offset(-10);
    }];
}
```

Everything gose well when there is more than one cell:

[image: Two cells aligned to the left]

However,the cell is in the center when there is only one cell:

[image: One cell in the center]

If I use `itemSize` instead of `estimatedItemSize`, it is OK:

```
layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(80, 30);
```

[image: Once cell aligned to the left]

I am really confused about this. Having the cell in the center of the collection view is not what I want but I also want to use Auto Layout so the cell's width adjusts itself.

So is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically this is the same issue I discuss here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52428617/341994

In sum, the feature you are trying to use, *self-sizing collection view cells*, doesn't work and has never worked. That is why, as you correctly say,

> If I use `itemSize` instead of `estimatedItemSize`, it will be OK

That's right! It isn't your bug; it's an iOS bug. Self-sizing collection view cells *do not work*. Either the app crashes or the flow layout is incorrect.

So that's the solution. Do not use `estimatedItemSize`. Instead, calculate the correct size yourself and provide it in your implementation of

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        // calculate/obtain correct size and return it
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Select `none` in the Estimate Size option. If the collection view has only one item, it will be left-aligned instead of being in the center.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Also,use custom `UICollectionViewLayout` can solve this problem:

**For Objective-C:**

```
@interface CQLeftSideLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout

@end

@implementation CQLeftSideLayout

- (NSArray<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *> *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {

    NSArray *attributes = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];

    if (attributes.count == 1) {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *currentAttributes = attributes.firstObject;
        currentAttributes.frame = CGRectMake(self.sectionInset.left, currentAttributes.frame.origin.y, currentAttributes.frame.size.width, currentAttributes.frame.size.height);
    }

    return attributes;

}

@end
```

**For Swift:**

```
class LeftSideLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

        let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)

        if attributes?.count == 1 {

            if let currentAttribute = attributes?.first {
                currentAttribute.frame = CGRect(x: self.sectionInset.left, y: currentAttribute.frame.origin.y, width: currentAttribute.frame.size.width, height: currentAttribute.frame.size.height)
            }

        }


        return attributes

    }

}
```