# Registering multiple cells in UICollectionView (swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

For `UICollectionViews`, is it possible to have multiple cell types?

**For example:**

```
media_cell

regular_cell

ad_cell
```

Would you just have to register them or do you have to include an if statement and change the layout according to some variable to achieve this effect.

**For example:**

```
if cell.ad == true {

}
```

The reason being, I want a slightly different sized cell for when an image is present. I guess resizing the cell could work but I haven't seen anything on this online.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:
 1. Register two(or more) cells.
 2.Configure cellforItem for each.
3. Configure sizeForItem for each.
First:

```
self.collectionView.register(SmallCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "smallCell")
self.collectionView.register(BigCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "bigCell")
```

And then:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     if dataSource[indexPath.item].hasImage {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: “smallCell”, for: indexPath) as! SmallCell
        let model = dataSource[indexPath.item]
        cell.model = model
        return cell
      } else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: “bigCell”, for: indexPath) as! BigCell
        let model = dataSource[indexPath.item]
        cell.model = model
        return cell
       }   
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
     if dataSource[indexPath.item].hasImage {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: cellHeight+100)
     } else {   
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: cellHeight)    
     }       
}
```

Comment: how do I reference the data source?

Comment: What do you mean?
dataSource is just an example array I made up.
Where each element in array has a Bool hasImage. 
This is just dummy code.
That if statement can be written a hundred different ways.
You yourself should know which indexPaths should have a image, which shouldn't.

Answer (score 4):

Two things and everything should be works:

1. You can register any number of cells in one collection view.
2. Check out self-sizing cells topic and you should not worry about different sizes of cells.

[Great tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells)

More info in this brilliant answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895311/uicollectionview-self-sizing-cells-with-auto-layout)

Good luck :)

Comment: When you say register any number of cells do you mean any number of instances or different types of cells?

Comment: any types of cells