# how can i use withReuseIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

How can I use multiple `withReuseIdentifier` ?

and here is the code
because i have 4 button doesn't work 
when i use Identifier "1" the other buttons dosen't wrok

and here is the code

```
extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource
{
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return interests3.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "1", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! interestCollectionViewCell
    cell.interest2 = self.interests3[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}
```

new code

```
    import UIKit

class interestCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell
{

    var interest2: Interest1! {
        didSet {
            updateUI()

        }

    }
    @IBOutlet weak var futerdimageview: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var interstTitleLabel: UILabel!


    private func updateUI()
    {
        interstTitleLabel.text! = interest2.title
        futerdimageview.image = interest2.featuredImage!


    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

and this code

```
    import UIKit

class Interest1
{
    var title = ""
    var description = ""
    var featuredImage: UIImage!
    var button1: UIButton!
    var button2: UIButton!
    var button3: UIButton!
    var button4: UIButton!



    init(title: String, featuredImage: UIImage!)
    {
        self.title = title
        self.featuredImage = featuredImage



    }

    static func createInterest() -> [Interest1]
    {

        return [
           Interest1(title: "One", featuredImage: UIImage(named:"001.png")!),
            Interest1(title: "Two", featuredImage: UIImage(named:"002.png")!),
            Interest1(title: "Three", featuredImage: UIImage(named:"003.png")!),
            Interest1(title: "Four", featuredImage: UIImage(named:"004.png")!),




        ]

    }
       }
```

Comment: Check conditions with indexPath

Comment: have a look at this [Registering multiple cells in UICollectionView (swift 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43971614/4056108)

Comment: exactly @chirag90

Comment: @chirag90 i tryed this code but i think i don't know how to use it

Comment: @faten in the thread it shows you need to register the cell with different reuse identifier. This needs to be put into viewdidload method. and in the collectionview cellForItemAt  you can than start using the other identifiers

Comment: i put the identifier , but when i run my app only one button work the first button i type ` if ((interests3[indexPath.item].button1) != nil) {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "1", for: indexPath) as! interestCollectionViewCell
            let model = interests3[indexPath.item]
            return cell
        }`

Comment: @chirag90 is there any Error ?

Comment: have you used different reuseable name for the other buttons?

Comment: @chirag90 yes i use "1" & "2" & "3" & "4"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, in your viewDidLoad method add

```
self.collectionView.register(interestCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "1")
self.collectionView.register(interestCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "2")
self.collectionView.register(interestCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "3")
self.collectionView.register(interestCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "4")
```

And change your collectionView cellForItemAt

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "1", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as? interestCollectionViewCell
        {
            cell.interest2 = self.interests3[indexPath.item]
            return cell
        } else if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "2", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as? interestCollectionViewCell
        {
            cell.interest2 = self.interests3[indexPath.item]
            return cell

        } else if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "3", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as? interestCollectionViewCell
        {
            cell.interest2 = self.interests3[indexPath.item]
            return cell

        } else if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "4", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as? interestCollectionViewCell
        {
            cell.interest2 = self.interests3[indexPath.item]
            return cell
        }
     return interestCollectionViewCell()
}
```

Comment: Missing return in a function expexted to return 'UICollectionViewCell' i got this error

Comment: in the class `interestCollectionViewCell` i got error :( ` private func updateUI()
    {
       interstTitleLabel.text = interest2.title
        futerdimageview.image = interest2.featuredImage!

    }`

Comment: i do like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JG7mWFcU0vk i want the image with button see the video and you will understand me what i want

Comment: inside the if statements in collectionview you will need to modify it to your needs, as currently i have just used the one you had.. And i am assuming they wont all be the same `cell.interest2 = self.interests3[indexPath.item]`

Comment: i got this Error in class `interestCollectionViewCell `  and the error is 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) ' i don't know why

Comment: You need to start debugging and doing google search, there are many questions on how to resolve optional values.

Comment: the Optional value in this code `private func updateUI()
    {
       interstTitleLabel.text = interest2.title
        futerdimageview.image = interest2.featuredImage!    
    }` the error come when i put your code

Comment: Let take this to [stackoverflow chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155081/swift-withreuseidentifier)

Comment: You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here :( did you see the video ? i will add some code for another tow class

Comment: Sorry dude, i am not watching 35 minutes of video. Like i mention put some break point in in your updateUI() function and step over it. to see what is coming out as nil.