# Unable to display multiple UICollectionViewCells with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am unable to display the second cell despite registering it to the collectionView. Does anyone know why this is the case? The cell exists as when I switch the row the other cell displays instead.

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white


        collectionView?.register(HeaderCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "HeaderCell")
        collectionView?.register(SummaryCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "SummaryCell")


    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return 1
        }
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if (indexPath.row == 0) {

            let cell1 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderCell", for: indexPath) as! HeaderCell

            return cell1

        } else {
            let cell2 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SummaryCell", for: indexPath) as! SummaryCell

            return cell2
        }

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 200)

    }

}
```

I have looked a [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43971382/registering-multiple-cells-in-uicollectionview-swift-3) but still unable to get it to work.

**P.S. I am programming everything programmatically.**

Comment: how many cells in your collection view? you have __1__, therefore the `HeaderCell` will appear only.

Comment: @Chace The cell exists as when I switch the row the other cell displays instead.Can you explain your point?

Comment: 2 cells at the moment

Comment: @Chace, I see __1__ cell only, where is the second one or more?

Comment: @Chace are you returning 2 in number of rows?

Comment: @TusharSharma, correct, I have added numberOfSection and returned 2 but I am just getting a repeat of the first cell. Also, I have two cells no? `HeaderCell` and `SummaryCell`

Comment: return 2 in numberOfItems.

Answer (score 4):

You have registered 2 cells but you are returning only 1 row.Try returning 2 items.

```
//numberOfItemsInSection
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return 2
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answer correctly/completely solves the issue. However I did use some of the suggestions to get it to work properly by adding the following:

```
override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 2
}
```

And changing `indexPath.row` to `indexPath.section`

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        let cell1 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderCell", for: indexPath) as! HeaderCell

        return cell1

    } else {
        let cell2 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SummaryCell", for: indexPath) as! SummaryCell

        return cell2
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you don't need the trailing else statement