# AutoSizing cells: cell width equal to the CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, autosize

I'm using AutoSizing cells with Autolayout and UICollectionView.

I can specify constraints in code on cell initialization:

```
  func configureCell() {
    snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
      make.width.equalToSuperview()
    }
  }
```

However, the app crashes as the cell hasn't been yet added to the `collectionView`.

**Questions**

1. At which stage of the `cell`'s lifecycle it is possible to add a
   constraint with `cell`'s `width`?
2. Is there any default way of making a `cell`'swidth`equal to the`
   width`of the`collectionView`without accessing an instance of`
   UIScreen`or`UIWindow`?

**Edit**
The question is not duplicate, as it is not about how to use the AutoSizing cells feature, but at which stage of the cell lifecycle to apply constraints to achieve the desired result **when** working with AutoLayout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UICollectionView Self Sizing Cells with Auto Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895311/uicollectionview-self-sizing-cells-with-auto-layout)

Comment: @OliverAtkinson not a duplicate, please take a look at the edit note.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To implement self-sizing collection view cells you need to do two things:

1. Specify `estimatedItemSize` on `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`
2. Implement `preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_:)` on your cell

---

### 1. Specifying `estimatedItemSize` on `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

> The default value of this property is CGSizeZero. Setting it to any other value causes the collection view to query each cell for its actual size using the cell’s preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_:) method. If all of your cells are the same height, use the itemSize property, instead of this property, to specify the cell size instead.

This is *just an estimate* which is used to calculate the content size of the scroll view, set it to something sensible.

```
let collectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
collectionViewFlowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 100)
```

---

### 2. Implement `preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_:)` on your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass

```
override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
    let autoLayoutAttributes = super.preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(layoutAttributes)

    // Specify you want _full width_
    let targetSize = CGSize(width: layoutAttributes.frame.width, height: 0)

    // Calculate the size (height) using Auto Layout
    let autoLayoutSize = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targetSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority.required, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority.defaultLow)
    let autoLayoutFrame = CGRect(origin: autoLayoutAttributes.frame.origin, size: autoLayoutSize)

    // Assign the new size to the layout attributes
    autoLayoutAttributes.frame = autoLayoutFrame
    return autoLayoutAttributes
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's the part 2 that I haven't implemented. With this approach the multitasking should work fine and there is no need to use the dummy-cell approach.

I've updated your answer to match the latest Swift syntax.

Comment: This works for layout, but I could not get it to cleanly animate insertions, deletions, and cell expansion without using the delegate sizeForItem approach.  If someone does have a clean solution for that, I would love to know.  In the meantime, I have a sample with my various attempts here: https://github.com/chrisco314/CollectionView-AutoLayout. It works cleanly on the third tab, using sizeForItem...

Comment: Hey Oliver 
Thanks for posting. This works like charm

Comment: what if I have cells of different size? Why must I set `estimatedItemSize`?

Comment: estimatedItemSize is a guess to allow the scrollBar to work, it has to be set to allow for the collection view to perform the rest of the calculations

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to implement [sizeForItemAt:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout) to calculate the size.

We've also used a "sizing cell" if your cells have variable height.  Eg:

```
class MyFancyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    class func cellSize(_ content: SomeContent, withWidth width: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
        sizingCell.content = content
        sizingCell.updateCellLayout(width)
        return sizingCell.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingExpandedSize)
    }

    fileprivate static let sizingCell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ContentCell", owner: nil, options: nil)!.first as! ContentCell    

    func updateCellLayout(width: CGFloat) {
        //Set constraints and calculate size    
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not an AutoSizing cells feature. I am familiar with this method. While it works perfectly, it looks rather like a hack.