# Have a fixed width of collectionView cell and dynamic height

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on a rebuild of UI on mobile App. I've changed my tableView by CollectionView (for have two columns of cells)

I've achieve the work to have dynamic heigh on cell and that work perfectly, as you can see (iOS left and Android right) I'm trying to achieve the android UI with iOS.

[image: Ios and android version]

Currently that what I have follow to achieve that :
https://www.vadimbulavin.com/collection-view-cells-self-sizing/

I've trying to set fixed width but that's automatically shape to the content.

I think that probably a little thing but I havent work from long time on iOS, so I'm looking for explain to achieve the fixed width size

The controller contain only that :

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout!{
    didSet {

        self.collectionViewFlowLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
    }
}
```

I havent do the 'max width' part of tutorial.
All label inside cell have left right constraint fixed, 0 lines and word wrap line break

Thank !

Have a nice day

Benjamin

Comment: Here is the solution -> https://www.raywenderlich.com/4829472-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49616214/1780632 checkout this answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AutoSizing cells: cell width equal to the CollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49616060/autosizing-cells-cell-width-equal-to-the-collectionview)

Comment: Thank that was exactly that, I haven't found this message before, but that exactly what I need, thank you guy :

Comment: @Benjamin have you solve issue? I have tried Hemant Singh Rathore but not working

Answer (score 0):

Well, as i see from screenshot, you already have auto height on each cell.

Set fixed width for CollectionViewCell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    var height:CGFloat = 0.0
    if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        height = layout.itemSize.height
    }
    let screenSize = UIScreen.main

    let wi = screenSize.bounds.size.width/2 // can calculate gap between two columns 

    return CGSize(width: wi, height: height)

}
```

Comment: It's look like the width are not fixed with this, I've line with 1 or 2 columns and different width at every cell

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a custom layout of class `UICollectionViewLayout` and set it to your collection view. There are a lot of Pinterest like collection view tutorials. You can check [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4829472-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest)