# Grid Layout in CollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

So i have a collectionViewController that I am trying to implement a grid layout in. I know that the sizeForItemAt controls the size but no matter how many times I play with it I just can't get it to be a three by three grid and it's really confusing me. Any help is greatly appreciated. I only added the sizeForItemAt method to save everyone some time.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = (view.frame.width - 2)/3
    return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
}
```

This is what my VC currently looks like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGG7l.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UICollectionView Self Sizing Cells with Auto Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895311/uicollectionview-self-sizing-cells-with-auto-layout)

Comment: did you check your `collectionView.contentOffset`

Comment: try to set the `minimumLineSpacing` to zero

Comment: @QuocNguyen how would the contentOffset change anything

Comment: @mazen I have it set to zero

Comment: @SJackson193 Your item width has been calculated by view.frame.width, it's not right if your collectionView has contentOffset

Answer (score 2):

Conform to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` (docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout))

eg:

```
class YourClassName: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate {
// ...
}
```

Note, from the docs:

> The flow layout object expects the collection view’s delegate object
>   to adopt this protocol. Therefore, implement this protocol on object
>   assigned to your collection view’s delegate property.

So in your `viewDidLoad` set:

`collectionView.delegate = self`

and implement the below to calc the cell size:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    // Number of cells
    let collectionViewWidth = collectionView.bounds.width/3.0 
    let collectionViewHeight = collectionViewWidth

    return CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth, height: collectionViewHeight)
}
```

Comment: im lost this didn't do anything differnet from what I already had