# Why is autosize collectoinviewcell is not working?

Tags: ios, tableview, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

As far as I am aware, if you set `estimatedItemSize` of `collectionviewlayout` to a non-zero value, the self-sizing will start, but it's not working for me.

You can obtain the working copy [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bREZOxB0NO7oYnmRSBJKCs219EBnZx9j) if you want to play around with it.

Comment: You have a collectionView inside one of you cells.  What is the behavior that you seeking from that?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already know about systemLayoutSizeFitting?

I think this has been answered already.  Have a look at [Daniel Galasko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1652402/daniel-galasko)'s answer, here:

[UICollectionView Self Sizing Cells with Auto Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895311/uicollectionview-self-sizing-cells-with-auto-layout?answertab=votes#tab-top)

In his answer, he even references a GitHub project that he put together, that you can download and play with:

https://github.com/danielgalasko/DGSelfSizingCollectionViewCells/tree/master