# Self sizing collection view cell size problem

Tags: swift, autolayout, collectionview

I'm trying to set a self sizing collection view with some data but the cells will layout accordingly only after I tap on a cell and reload the data again. Tried with layoutIfNeeded() etc. but won't work.

[image: initial load]
[image: after reloading data]

Comment: Check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/45830849/7696238

Comment: Provide code? Constraints you set?

Answer (score 0):

It works if I replace UICollectionViewCell with a plain UIView in the xib file.