# How to make self-sizing cells for dynamic UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, ios9

I have `UIScrollView` with horizontal scrolling direction and dynamic height (user can change the height when finger moved). I need to make cells able to resize itself when `UIScrollView` change height (`UICollectionView.frame.size = SomeCell.frame.size`).

I try to make this with set cells width and height constraints to superview (`UICollectionView`) but its not working (all cells have some position).

**Note:** I want to keep compatibility with devices on iOS 9 and newer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UICollectionView Self Sizing Cells with Auto Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895311/uicollectionview-self-sizing-cells-with-auto-layout)

Comment: If you use auto-layout like in the duplicate I mentioned, you can just update the height constraint and then the cell should update. You might have to call some layout methods after updating the constraint's constant.

Comment: I try it, but its not working. All cells equal estimatedSize in flowLayout.

Comment: Have you set that to automatic? `flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = .automaticSize` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42948877/3397217))

Comment: I need compatible with iOS 9+