# Dynamically increase UICollectionViewCell size according to the content

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to create a vertical UICollectionView over a horizontal collection view, and in my vertical collection view are three items: WKWebview, UILabel, and a another UICollectionView.
The problem is, how can I define the height of the vertical cell based on the content of it?
I have tried different approaches but none of them seem to work.

The vertical UICollectionViewCell contains these three items:

```
class ContentCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    lazy var articleWebView: WKWebView  = {
        var webView = WKWebView()
        webView.isHidden = false
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.backgroundColor = .blue
        webView.scrollView.delegate = self
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return webView
    }()


var upNextLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Up Next"
    label.textColor = .black
    label.font = label.font.withSize(20)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    return label
}()

    lazy var upNextCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.isHidden = true
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv.backgroundColor = .white
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self
        return cv
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setUpView()
        let myURL = URL(string:"https://google.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        articleWebView.load(myRequest)

    }

    func setUpView() {

        addSubview(articleWebView)
        addSubview(upNextLabel)
        addSubview(upNextCollectionView)
        articleWebView.navigationDelegate = self
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint
            .constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[v0]-18-[v1(60)]-18-[v2(300)]-0-|", options:
                NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions() ,metrics: nil, views: ["v0": articleWebView,"v1":upNextLabel,
                                                                                                                                            "v2":upNextCollectionView]))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions() , metrics: nil, views: ["v0": articleWebView]))

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-16-[v0]|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions() , metrics: nil, views: ["v0": upNextLabel]))

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions() , metrics: nil, views: ["v0": upNextCollectionView]))       

        upNextCollectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "upNextContentCell")

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "upNextContentCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = .brown
        return cell
    }


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: frame.width, height: 100)
}


func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
    var frame = webView.frame

    //frame.size.width = frame.width
    frame.size.height = 1

    webView.frame = frame
    frame.size.height = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
    webView.frame = frame;  
}

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }

}
```

The vertical Collection view code is like this

```
class DetailCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

lazy var contentCollectionView: UICollectionView = {

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical

    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cv.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.delegate = self

    return cv
}()


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setUpViews()
}

let cellId = "contentCell"
let upNextCellId = "upNextCellId"

func setUpViews() {

    addSubview(contentCollectionView)

    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-1-[v0]-1-|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions() , metrics: nil, views: ["v0": contentCollectionView]))

    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[v0]-0-|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions() , metrics: nil, views: ["v0": contentCollectionView]))

    contentCollectionView.register(ContentCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "contentCell")

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "contentCell", for: indexPath) as! ContentCell
    cell.backgroundColor = .lightGray       
    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    /// the height here is just a random height just to see the ouput
    return CGSize(width: frame.width , height: 6000)
}
```

I want to layout this cell in such a way that all my content will look properly aligned. What do i need to do.

Comment: For self -sizing collectionView cells you can follow this  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895311/uicollectionview-self-sizing-cells-with-auto-layout

Comment: That answer didnt solved my problem