# Issues setting constraints on UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, autolayout, constraints

I created an UICollectionViewCell (.xib) and I just wanted to add a label and some simple constraints there, as such:

[image: Simple Constraints]

However, doing this messes up everything. No matter the size I chose on `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`, the cell will always use the size of the label! What am I doing wrong here? Am I supposed to not use constraints on CollectionViewItems and instead `translatesMaskIntoConstraints = true`?
Thanks!

**edit:** Here's what I expected:
[image: Expected Result]

And here's what I actually have (as soon as I add the constraints):
[image: Result with constraints]

**edit2:** Fixed! By changing the label's content hugging priority to 10 (for example, or lower). But...why exactly if there are no other constraints in the view? If somebody can answer it, I would be very grateful, cause I could just answer this question and give this solution but I can't explain why exactly it fixed it, so it's not a proper answer anyway.

Comment: Please share expected result and currently result for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways: you can delegate to a cell to calculate own height or you can set fixed size for height.

If you want the first case, please, read other [related answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895311/uicollectionview-self-sizing-cells-with-auto-layout)

If you want fixed size, you should make a fixed height on the label. Label is calculating own size based on `contentSize`, so your constraints are failed in the matter of fixed size of your cell

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. Although, I'm not quite sure you understood exactly my issue. Could you check the updated question, please? Thanks!

Comment: @Mykod hello! Hugging is working because then your cell size is more prioritized in sizing. See the nature of your problem: UILabel has its own size based on content, so due to its size and its offsets of the edges, it's trying to size your cell. What you can do: align not by leading/trailing/bottom/top, but constraint its to center of cell