# How to dynamically size CollectionViewCell as per UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

I'm creating a suggestion/tags view. Which is basically a horizontal `uicollectionview`. I've a custom cell in which I just have one label with no autoresizing or auto constraints. And I've an array `var tagsArray = ["Label", "A Long Label", "A very long label"]` which I am using in the **collectionView delegate methods as:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tagsArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let size = (tagsArray[indexPath.row] as NSString).size(withAttributes: nil)
    return size
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TagCell", for: indexPath) as! TagCollectionViewCell
    cell.tagLabel.text = tagsArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell

}
```

**The second function `collectionViewLayout` is something that I've picked form stack overflow but when I run it there is no effect on the UILabel.**

Here is the output:
[image]

Comment: You can use this library for tag view: https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView

Comment: Add your output image.

Comment: @dahiya_boy added the output image.

Comment: @ChaudhryTalha You need to use [this method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1524729-boundingrect) to get the exact width of the string. Add some margin after that so that your UI looks good. I had done same in Obj-c , [link](https://github.com/thedahiyaboy/TDTagIndex/blob/master/TDTagListCollection/TDTagListCollection/ViewController.m), as its one line code so you can convert it ito swift too.

Comment: @dahiya_boy I've added `let tagSize = (tagsArray[indexPath.row] as NSString).boundingRect(with: (tagsArray[indexPath.row] as NSString).size(withAttributes: nil), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: nil, context: nil).size` by following the objective c link and then `return CGSize(width: tagSize.width, height: 40)` in the `sizeForItemAt` function but it still didn't work.

Comment: This may [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895311/uicollectionview-self-sizing-cells-with-auto-layout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to calculate the size of the strings that you want to display. Do the following:

1. Set `collectionView`'s height equal to the expected height of tags.
2. Set `tagLabel`'s `leading`, `trailing`, `top` and `bottom` constraints equal to the corresponding cell's `contentView` constraints.
3. Remove your implementation of `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize`. The cell size will be calculated automatically if you don't use a custom value for `estimatedItemSize`. If you want to be sure, add `(collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout)?.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize` to the function where you setup all views.

You will see the following result:

[image: Running on iPhone 11 Pro Max simulator]

Comment: @LalKrishna Tried this code on iOS 11 and iOS 12 and it works fine.

Comment: how to deal with `contentView` if it is not displayed in xib?

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov I think you should ask a new question. You can also use https://ru.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: No, I think your answer is incomplete

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov `contentView` should be visible in the xib file. Or did you hide it for some reason?

Comment: `contentView` is visible in table cells but not in collection cells. So I ask how to deal with it. I can't create cells purely programmatically.

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov Normally `contentView` is visible in the xib file. That's why you should ask a new question for **how to deal with contentView if it is not displayed in xib?**.

Comment: I finally found it. When you create `UICollectionViewCell` with "New file..." menu there is no `contentView`. It appears when you drag cell into xib only. Checked what happens inside xib code - `contentView` exists and anyways you place subviews inside it. BUT: in the first case you work with `contentView` even if IB doesn't show it

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov Sounds great. Hope the solution works for you now.