# How to populate UITableView from the bottom upwards?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios8

is it possible to reverse the order of a tableView. I have searched a lot for a solution but all the results have not quite been a solution to what I am trying to achieve. They all suggest scrolling to the last position of a table with `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` and populating the data in reverse. But this doesn't work if the table content is dynamic and in some instances not all the cells have data. For example in a normal tableView the order is:

---

### label 1

### label 2

### label 3

### empty

### empty

scroll direction
v
V

---

the desired result would be:
scroll direction
^
^

### empty

### empty

### empty

### label 3

### label 2

### label 1

---

in this example if I used the suggested method of `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` and use the length of the array of objects, I would only get the third cell from the top. And end up with something like this:

---

unwanted outcome:

### label 3

### label 2

### label 1

### empty

### empty

scroll direction
v
V

---

any help would be great thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the issue.  Why are the empty rows at the bottom?  How are you representing these empty rows internally?

Comment: One HACKY solution would be to flip the table view, and flip each cell in the table view. That way, you populate the table normally, and the first cell will appear at the bottom. Simplest way to do it, IMHO.

Comment: @kai Taylor I had a small mistake in my code, try it now please.

Comment: `cell.setTitle.text = myArray.reversed()[indexPath.row]` Reversing your array will do the trick.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To populate `UITableView` **from the bottom**:

```
- (void)updateTableContentInset {
    NSInteger numRows = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];
    CGFloat contentInsetTop = self.tableView.bounds.size.height;
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        contentInsetTop -= [self tableView:self.tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0]];
        if (contentInsetTop <= 0) {
            contentInsetTop = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(contentInsetTop, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

To reverse the order of elements:

```
dataSourceArray = dataSourceArray.reverseObjectEnumerator.allObjects;
```

**Swift 4.2/5** version:

```
func updateTableContentInset() {
    let numRows = self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)
    var contentInsetTop = self.tableView.bounds.size.height
    for i in 0..<numRows {
        let rowRect = self.tableView.rectForRow(at: IndexPath(item: i, section: 0))
        contentInsetTop -= rowRect.size.height
        if contentInsetTop <= 0 {
            contentInsetTop = 0
            break
        }
    }
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: contentInsetTop,left: 0,bottom: 0,right: 0)
}
```

**Swift 3/4.0** version:

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(contentInsetTop, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: @kai Taylor I had a small mistake in my code, try it now please.

Comment: there also needs to be an allowance for the height of the first section header since you can't remove it?

Comment: @kai Taylor Please specify, do you want to use section headers and there is a problem with it?

Comment: Sorry, your answer is excellent and I am able to adjust it for my needs with and without headers. I just thought I would point out the issue for those with the default header setting using (blank header with height 20) for anyone who might come across this answer in future who may not understand why they are getting extra padding. Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortuantely this solution won't work when you are using AutoLayout on your UITableViewCells which can have dynamic heights.

Comment: Any solution that works with auto-layout / dynamic cell heights?

Comment: syntax and logic changed since 3.0 ? I'm getting: `Cannot call value of non-function type 'UITableView!'` at the *syntax changed* line: `tableView(self.tableView, heightForRowAt: IndexPath(item: i, section: 0))`

Comment: @DavidSeek I had syntax error, it's already fixed. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @KlimczakM Please can you tell how to use this?

Comment: @AnirudhaMahale You just need to call the `updateTableContentInset` function after everything is set up, it can be even in `viewWillAppear` method.

Comment: Should This method be called every time i reload the data

Comment: I have a tableview with dynamic cells my problem is there is overscroll is there a way to fix this??

Comment: Something is wrong with `contentInsetTop -= tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: IndexPath(item: i, section: 0))`

Comment: @Jonny what do you mean? Provide some details so I or someone else could help you.

Comment: Actually David Seek already commented on it above. Might be a swift syntax mismatch.

Comment: @Jonny Ok, got this, already fixed, please see updated answer, thanks for noticing.

Comment: Okay. Looks like the answer below which I ended up using - using autosized cell heights. Anyway, it causes jumpy behavior, especially if user scrolls up a bit in the table view. Even avoiding to set the inset to 0 when it is already 0 does not help. It's so weird, it seems that only inspecting those values of the tableview causes it to change some on-screen UI. Specifically the table view has a tendency to jump down to last row. This is really hard to get right.

Comment: @Jonny Seem weird, I'll check this out, maybe I'll find something.

Comment: Not sure if I will find an answer but it seems that calling `rectForRow` specifically - just to READ the value - causes the tableview to recalculate/redisplay/whatever some things in the UI. Even if I comment out the set to `tableView.contentInset = xxx`. Might be an autolayout issue and I guess this answer didn't cater for that.

Comment: `let numRows = tableView(self.tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: 0)` fails for me with `Cannot call value of non-function type 'UITableView'` but
`let numRows = self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)` works

Comment: @RomanVasilyev You're right - I've updated the answer. Thank you!

Comment: @KlimczakM Perhaps you could add a `break` after `contentInsetTop = 0`, if you've reached zero already, there's no need to evaluate further rows. (I see the ObjC version has it already).

Answer (score 33):

first reverse uitableview

```
    tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale (1,-1);
```

then reverse cell in cell create.

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

    ...

    cell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale (1,-1);
```

Comment: This is a simple solution

Comment: Good one, and I hope it'll not disturbed on different devices with RTL too. If its please let me know.

Answer (score 29):

**Swift 4.0 and 4.2 version**

First reverse UITableView in viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
}
```

Then reverse the cell in cellForRowAt.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? MyTableViewCell else { fatalError() }

        cell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: your solution is right but the Delete option is not transforming. Can you please help me out if you have solution?

Comment: I don't understand your issue, can you elaborate your problem.

Comment: Please see this image and you will get the Delete is looking weird. https://imgur.com/D9x2KG7

Comment: As you know we are transforming cell content, so it should transform everything in cell.

Comment: Nice, it worked if then keyboard comes up

Comment: it works for me, Thanks!

Comment: I am trying to use a reverse table view for the chat app ... the only problem with this approach is the first message is appearing on the bottom ... and I need to show it on the top ...

Answer (score 4):

Here is a refined solution of KlimczakM´s solution that works with autolayouted tableview cells (as well as the fixed ones). This solution also works with sections, section headers and section footers.

**Swift 3.0**:

```swift
func updateTableContentInset(forTableView tv: UITableView) {
    let numSections = tv.numberOfSections
    var contentInsetTop = tv.bounds.size.height -
        (self.navigationBar?.frame.size.height ?? 0)

    for section in 0..<numSections {
        let numRows = tv.numberOfRows(inSection: section)
        let sectionHeaderHeight = tv.rectForHeader(inSection: section).size.height
        let sectionFooterHeight = tv.rectForFooter(inSection: section).size.height
        contentInsetTop -= sectionHeaderHeight + sectionFooterHeight
        for i in 0..<numRows {
            let rowHeight = tv.rectForRow(at: IndexPath(item: i, section: section)).size.height
            contentInsetTop -= rowHeight
            if contentInsetTop <= 0 {
                contentInsetTop = 0
                break
            }
        }
        // Break outer loop as well if contentInsetTop == 0
        if contentInsetTop == 0 {
            break
        }
    }
    tv.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(contentInsetTop, 0, 0, 0)
}
```

**NOTE:**

Above code is untested but should work.
Just make sure that you cope for the height of any navbar or tabbar and you'll be fine. In the code above i only do that for the navbar!

Answer (score 4):

Don't bother to write the code by yourself.
Why don't you use ReverseExtension. Its very easy and will give you all required results. Please follow this url
https://github.com/marty-suzuki/ReverseExtension

**Note:**  Whenever you need to add a new cell, please insert newly added model at zeroth index of datasource array, so new cell should add at bottom.  Otherwise it would add the cell at top and you would get confused again.

Comment: Any solution for CollectionView?

Comment: @aaban This library as an open issue regarding the content inset. Can you help me over that. I'm not able to set the bottom inset of the tableview.

Answer (score 3):

The simple way is use like UILabel multiple lines + autolayout.
-> UITableView should resize it base on it content(aka intrinsic layout).
Create your tableview and set base class following:

```
class IntrinsicTableView: UITableView {

override var contentSize:CGSize {
    didSet {
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
}

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    return CGSize(width: UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric, height: contentSize.height)
}
```

}

Now set left right and bottom layout constraints for your tableview pin to it parent view.
The most important is top layout constraint should set to great than or equal 0, This condition guaranteed table will not tall than it parent view.

Answer (score 1):

I did in cellForRowAt method:

```
let reverseIndex = myArray.count-indexPath.row-1

let currCellData = myArray.object(at: reverseIndex)
```

and then you continue working with currCellData

Answer (score 1):

```
     //Add these lines where you want to reload your tableView  
let indexpath = IndexPath(row: self.Array.count-1, section: 0)
                                self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexpath, at: .top, animated: true)
                                self.updateTableContentInset()
    
    
    
    //Add this function below
    func updateTableContentInset() {
        let numRows = self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)
        var contentInsetTop = self.tableView.bounds.size.height
        for i in 0..<numRows {
            let rowRect = self.tableView.rectForRow(at: IndexPath(item: i, section: 0))
            contentInsetTop -= rowRect.size.height
            if contentInsetTop <= 0 {
                contentInsetTop = 0
                break
            }
        }
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: contentInsetTop,left: 0,bottom: 0,right: 0)
    }
```

Comment: in my case, I have multiple sections with different numbers of rows in every section and can't manage to keep the state of uitableview on reverse pagination...

Answer (score 1):

I you want that every new cell should appear from the bottom of the tableView, use this:-

1. Invert the tableView:
   `myTableView.transform = CGAffineTransform (scaleX: -1,y: -1)`
2. Invert the cells also:
   `cell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransform (scaleX: -1,y: -1)`
3. Now populate your tabelViewDataSource in opposite direction, like if you are using an array, then you may do like this:
   `myTableViewData.insert(<Your New Array Element>), at: 0)`

Answer (score 0):

This solution adjust the content inset **as the content size changes** using KVO. It also takes the content inset into account when scrolling to top as simply scrolling to `CGPointZero` will scroll to the top of the content instead of scrolling to the top of the table.

```
-(void)startObservingContentSizeChanges
{
    [self.tableView addObserver:self forKeyPath:kKeyPathContentSize options:0 context:nil];
}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:kKeyPathContentSize] && object == self.tableView)
    {
        // difference between content and table heights. +1 accounts for last row separator
        CGFloat height = MAX(self.tableView.frame.size.height - self.tableView.contentSize.height, 0) + 1;

        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(height, 0, 0, 0);

        // "scroll" to top taking inset into account
        [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -height) animated:NO];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.01 - Other solution can be, rotate and flip the tableView.

```
self.tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: (-(CGFloat)(M_PI)))
self.tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: -view.frame.width, y: view.frame.height)
```

[UITableView anchor rows to bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679835/uitableview-anchor-rows-to-bottom/41253989#41253989)

Answer (score -2):

If you have an array of object you display in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, lets say `dataArray` you can reverse it, or in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`
you can do something like that:

```
NSString *yourObject = dataArray[[dataArray count] - 1 - indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = yourObject
```

I assume you keep strings in dataArray.

Comment: This approach will give the result I showed in the third example. The order will be reversed, but will not start from the physical bottom of the table view.