# Layout SwiftUI List cells from bottom upward

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is there a way to customize SwiftUI List so cells are displayed from bottom to top?

Related question with UITableView: [How to populate UITableView from the bottom upwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28105905/how-to-populate-uitableview-from-the-bottom-upwards)

Comment: I'm not sure if `List` has this ability (yet) but what you (obviously) could do is to just use a UITableView with the linked answer inside a custom UIViewRepresentable-View. [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewrepresentable)

Answer (score 2):

```
struct FlipEffect: GeometryEffect {
    func effectValue(size: CGSize) -> ProjectionTransform {
        let t = CGAffineTransform(a: 1, b: 0, c: 0, d: -1, tx: 0, ty: size.height)
        return ProjectionTransform(t)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(0..<100) { item in
            Text("hello, world")
                .modifier(FlipEffect())
        }
        .modifier(FlipEffect())
    }
}
```

Comment: Ummm... that's a really cool hack!  But it literally does a full flip transform.  If you have text, you'll need to stand on your head with a mirror to read it, lol.  But so cool, gonna keep this trick around, thanks!