# How to transform Delete option in Tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cgaffinetransform

I've transformed the tableview and tableview cell to fill the cell from bottom to top using [How to populate UITableView from the bottom upwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28105905/how-to-populate-uitableview-from-the-bottom-upwards/55757125?noredirect=1#comment104337992_55757125) post.

But I want to transform the swipe to Delete option as well.
Please refer the image for more detail.

[image]

You can see the Delete option is not transform as the tableview.
Any helpful answer will be very appreciated.

Comment: Why won't you try this -> https://github.com/marty-suzuki/ReverseExtension

Comment: @dahiya_boy this is the same as behaviour that I've. I downloaded and checked the delete option and getting the same behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First reverse UITableView in viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
}
```

Then reverse the cell in cellForRowAt.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? MyTableViewCell else { fatalError() }

            cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
            cell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)

            return cell
        }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: nil) { (action, indexPath) in
            // delete item at indexPath
        }

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 75, height: tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath).height)))
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        label.text = "Delete"
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(label.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
        label.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()



        if let cgImage = image?.cgImage {
            let rotada3 = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: image!.scale, orientation: .downMirrored)
            delete.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: rotada3)

        }


        return [delete]
    }
```

Here on `editActionsForRowAt` I did a work around to print image with mirrored text

Comment: I tried with the same as per your code but didn't work it. Please check this image https://imgur.com/2kOWkDr

Comment: @GautamSareriya, I have tested it now it is working

Comment: just one small correction in cellForRowAt method to transform the cell, use only cell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1) and rest of the code will be same. And it will work. Thanks :)

Comment: I've corrected the mistake, Please mark it as correct answer to let other knows

Comment: it's working only for 1 to 3 line of message cell. But if the message cell increase more than 3 line then it will not working. Please check the image https://imgur.com/BIxPElG.

Comment: You can change the height of the label to be equals cell. You have the index so call tableview.rectForRow(at: IndexPath)

Answer (score 0):

Transform tableview

```
tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -(.pi))
```

Then within cell

```
cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi)
```

Comment: Hi, not working as per your code I tried it. You can check the image https://imgur.com/4rc9ynI